# Groovy script to set SonarQube server settings in Jenkins programatically

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, sonarqube

I have a SonarQube server set up and the SonarQbue plugin set up for Jenkins. I know I have to set two settings; one in 'Manage Jenkins' > 'Configure System' > 'SonarQube Servers' and another (i.e. SonarQube Scanner setup) in 'Manage Jenkins' > 'Global Tool Configuration' > 'SonarQube Scanner'.

I searched on how to set the values of the above settings using Groovy script. [This script from GitHub](https://github.com/hayderimran7/useful-jenkins-groovy-init-scripts/blob/master/sonar-artifactory-settings.groovy) was not helping when I tried in Groovy script console as I got the following error:

`groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarInstallation(java.lang.String, java.lang.Boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, hudson.plugins.sonar.model.TriggersConfig, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)`

I couldn't find any documentation on these API's either. Requesting help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the following solution:

```
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.plugins.sonar.*
import hudson.plugins.sonar.model.TriggersConfig
import hudson.tools.*

// Required environment variables
def sonar_name = "New setting"
def sonar_server_url = "http://sonarqube:9000"
def sonar_auth_token = "<token>"
def sonar_mojo_version = ''
def sonar_additional_properties = ''
def sonar_triggers = new TriggersConfig()
def sonar_additional_analysis_properties = ''
def sonar_runner_version = '3.1.0.1141'

def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()

Thread.start {

    sleep(10000)
    println("Configuring SonarQube...")

    // Get the GlobalConfiguration descriptor of SonarQube plugin.
    def SonarGlobalConfiguration sonar_conf = instance.getDescriptor(SonarGlobalConfiguration.class)

    def sonar_inst = new SonarInstallation(
        sonar_name,
        sonar_server_url,
        sonar_auth_token,
        sonar_mojo_version,
        sonar_additional_properties,
        sonar_triggers,
        sonar_additional_analysis_properties
    )

    // Only add the new Sonar setting if it does not exist - do not overwrite existing config
    def sonar_installations = sonar_conf.getInstallations()
    def sonar_inst_exists = false
    sonar_installations.each {
        installation = (SonarInstallation) it
        if (sonar_inst.getName() == installation.getName()) {
            sonar_inst_exists = true
            println("Found existing installation: " + installation.getName())
        }
    }
    if (!sonar_inst_exists) {
        sonar_installations += sonar_inst
        sonar_conf.setInstallations((SonarInstallation[]) sonar_installations)
        sonar_conf.save()
    }

    // Step 2 - Configure SonarRunner
    println("Configuring SonarRunner...")
    def desc_SonarRunnerInst = instance.getDescriptor("hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation")
    def sonarRunnerInstaller = new SonarRunnerInstaller(sonar_runner_version)
    def installSourceProperty = new InstallSourceProperty([sonarRunnerInstaller])
    def sonarRunner_inst = new SonarRunnerInstallation("New Setting SonarRunner " + sonar_runner_version, "", [installSourceProperty])

    // Only add our Sonar Runner if it does not exist - do not overwrite existing config
    def sonar_runner_installations = desc_SonarRunnerInst.getInstallations()
    def sonar_runner_inst_exists = false
    sonar_runner_installations.each {
        installation = (SonarRunnerInstallation) it
        if (sonarRunner_inst.getName() == installation.getName()) {
            sonar_runner_inst_exists = true
            println("Found existing installation: " + installation.getName())
        }
    }
    if (!sonar_runner_inst_exists) {
        sonar_runner_installations += sonarRunner_inst
        desc_SonarRunnerInst.setInstallations((SonarRunnerInstallation[]) sonar_runner_installations)
        desc_SonarRunnerInst.save()
    }

    // Save the state
    instance.save()
}
```

Hope it helps someone. Thanks.

Comment: auth token is not getting set , I have created credential which i want to set , but its not working if i pass credential name

Comment: same for me, sonar_auth_token is not set by some reason, i created it with secret text type

Comment: @BigBoss No not yet

Comment: @BigBoss You can take a look at this code [code](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-jenkins/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/sonar/SonarInstallation.java)
Code shown as a answer is using old deprecated Constructor of SonarInstallation which didnt had option to pass credential id , you can modify the constructor to pass credential id. Give it a try

Comment: I guess i tried but no luck, is it work for you? if yes can you send example? Thanks

Comment: this one is working:
def sonar = new SonarInstallation(
    'sonar-server',
    'test.com',
    'test-credentials',
    null,
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '',
    new TriggersConfig()
)

Comment: @BigBoss Nice to see you got it working , may be post complete code as an alternate answer